# Is it possible to check that MS word file is hand written or auto generated by using some converter?

Tags: comparison, desktop-application

I got one project with some requirements.

Basically my client provide data entry work.  In that he converts image files(scan copy of articles, forms etc) to document file (MS word) by typing manually.  For maintaining quality of that work he set some roles on documents text formatting like specific font, font size, paper size etc., and he compare image files with specific document for proofreading which is very time consuming task, and his some **smart employ** use some image to word converter for that conversion rather then typing manually. He pays a lot in the Data entry and he don't want automated converted files using some conversion software.

So basically he want two functionality in his project that,

1. to automate standard format proofreading process and
2. to automatically reject image to word converted files.

this is the all scenario and now **my question** is that

1. Is it possible to find out which file is manually type by employ and which is converted by using some conversion software?
2. Is it possible that we can check file for specific standard format?

Comment: eeeeeeeeevil. just saying~

Comment: You're trying to find a technical solution to a social problem.

Comment: Install a keystroke logger on the employee's computer, and compare the keys that it logs to the output he produces.

Answer (score 4):

For checking for the use of OCR software, find out whether the OCR software adds metadata to the file.

For checking for consistency with a specific format, write a VBA macro. MS Office VBA macros have access to the document object model. Of course, if you're going to that, you might as well just have the macro *set* the document's formatting to the required format.

I'm curious, though: does your client have a better reason for disallowing OCR than "I'm paying you for manual data entry so you can't use OCR"?

Comment: Yeah, that seems lame to me, too.  If someone can increase their output by OCRing, but maintain the same quality, who the fsck cares?  I say more power to 'im.

Comment: Great Idea, then someone will just write a macro to look for the same meta data and remove it. Utimiatly it's an arms race the no one can win, but +1 for the use of a macro to sett he formatting.